# Is asking the "I certify that information submitted is true?" question worthwhile?

Tags: forms, web-app

I recently watched a documentary on Netflix called *(Dis)Honesty – The Truth About Lies*.  In it, there was an example about how simply reminding the user about attesting to submitting honest information reduced the instances of cheating (they referred to it as demonstrating their "moral fiber").

At the risk of asking too many questions at once, have you found this to be true for forms on web applications?  Is there any data behind this?  If so, what would be the best copy for this type of question?

I am considering modifying our generic *"Submit"* button with text to read something like, *"This information is true to the best of my knowledge.  Please submit it."*  I've also seen checkboxes with a similar concept.

Edit:
We're working on a multi-page form (think of a loan application or rental application).  High accuracy/truth is important since we are making decisions relative to other applicants.

Comment: It very much depends on context - the type of information being given; how it's going to be used; whether it *matters* whether it's true or not; what 'cheating' means in the given scenario. We don't know anything about your particular context.

Comment: Sure, updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You might do two versions and A/B test them to compare the user reception and content results.

- One with confirmation checkbox (additional step) that blocks the
  'Submit' action.
- Second one could be sth simplified, like this:

[image]

It's clear call to action and should raise the awareness of the newcomer but would not block the flow of the frequent user.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that you are working on a product where:

> High accuracy/truth is important

It may be worthwhile including this confirmation step because:

1. It will start a feedback loop in the user's mind that asks "Did I in fact answer everything truthfully?"
2. It will encourage the behavior of revisiting fields in order to confirm that no errors or mistakes were made during the completion of the form (even if the user intended to answer truthfully, they may have entered erroneous information accidentally)